# Customize onscroll event

Tags: jquery, html, css, thymeleaf

Suppose I have a presentation page, made with `Thymeleaf`, in which I have a `table`. This `table` has 5 column but in one of them I can have more than an element:

```
 <table id="table1" data-toggle="table" data-search="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true">Code</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Furnisher(s)</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Description</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Category</th>
      <th data-sortable="true">Quantity</th>              
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr th:each="element : ${dto}">
      <td><span th:text="${dto.id}"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <td>
      <div class="furnisherList" onscroll="handleOnScroll(this)">
       <span th:each="supplier : *{dto.furnisherList}">
         <span th:text="${supplier.company_name}"></span>
         <br>
       </span>
      </div>
    </td>
    ...
    ... <!-- others column with at most 1 element -->
    ...
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Class `furnisherList` has the follow `css`:

```
.furnisherList {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 12px;
}
```

When there is more than one elements the column appears as follows:

[image]

Where *Magic* is the first element of the list and the others are hidden (overflowed) below it.

Now I like this graphic, the `table row` **must** be thin and the `scroll button` are well positioned but I would like to customize the `click event` on the `scroll button`.

I want to open a curtain (like a dropdown menu) when user click on the `scroll buttons` (whatever it is, up or down).

For now, I write a simple `JQuery` function to read the elements inside `furnisherList div`:

```
function handleOnScroll(element) {
  $(element).find('span').each(function() {
    $(this).find('span').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
  });
}
```

This works well except for the fact that, if I click (once) the `scroll button`, the function is firing (at least) twice!

I have tried with `event.preventDefault()`, `$(element).stopScroll()` but nothing works..

Can you help me??

---

I solved as **Ggs** says writing below code to the `Thymeleaf` page:

```
<div class="furnisherList">
  <span th:if="${#lists.size(dto.furnisher) > 1}">
    <select class="furnisherOptions">
      <option th:each="supplier : *{dto.furnisher}" th:text="${supplier.company_name}"></option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span th:unless="${#lists.size(dto.furnisher) > 1}" th:each="supplier : *{dto.furnisher}">
    <span th:text="${supplier.company_name}"></span>
    <br>
  </span>
</div>
```

The `furnisherList css`:

```
.furnisherList {
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  height: 12px;
}
```

The `furnisherOptions css`:

```
.furnisherOptions {
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-image: none;
  outline-offset: -2px;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

No need other `JQuery` function.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should totally use a Select input :

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and a function Change function to catch the select changed:

```
$( "#select" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```